# How to make system calls counter using deviare

Tags: c#, hook, deviare

I would like to hook all the functions calls of all running processes. I can hook certain function("ws2_32.dll!recv") of all processes using deviare by:

```
        CreateSpyMgr(out mgr);
        hook = mgr.CreateHook("ws2_32.dll!recv");
        hook.Attach(mgr.get_Processes(0));
        mgr.set_ReportProcessCreation(DeviareCommonLib.ReportMethod._create_process_hook_and_polling, 0);
        hook.set_HookNewProcesses(0, 1);
        hook.OnFunctionCalled += new DHookEvents_OnFunctionCalledEventHandler(hook_OnFunctionCalled);
        hook.Hook();
```

How can I hook all function calls instead of just one? is it possible?

Or should I create hooks collection(of all functions which is way hard) using INktSpyMgr::CreateHooksCollection and add hooks to it, then call hook method and pass the INktHooksEnum object as the parameter. Is this the only way to do this?

My aim is to make a tool that counts all system calls for each running process. Feel free to give any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

First a word of advice: be very *very* careful about which APIs you hook.  If anything you do within your hook method results in a call to one of the APIs you are hooking then you are creating an infinite recursion that could potentially wreck your computer.  Bear that in mind.  You'll probably want to filter out the API calls for your own process as well, otherwise you'll end up logging entries about the disk access caused by logging entries, and before you know it your memory is full and the hard drive is fully occupied with logging about logging.

There appears to be nothing in the Deviare API that allows you to create hooks on multiple methods - no wildcards or 'hook everything' calls - so you'll have to enumerate the APIs (see [`INktModule.ExportedFunctions`](http://www.nektra.com/products/deviare-api-hook-windows/doc-v2/interface_i_nkt_module_ab87a026897cef81e8df042138f748688.html#ab87a026897cef81e8df042138f748688) for some ideas) and hook them.  I'd suggest that you use a hook collection (see [`INktSpyMgr.CreateHookCollection`](http://www.nektra.com/products/deviare-api-hook-windows/doc-v2/interface_i_nkt_spy_mgr_aaa9b037c2fe58be5ab48bcd0ffd5e7e8.html#aaa9b037c2fe58be5ab48bcd0ffd5e7e8) and [`INktHooksEnum`](http://www.nektra.com/products/deviare-api-hook-windows/doc-v2/interface_i_nkt_hooks_enum.html)) so that you can setup all your hooks and then attach and detach them in one operation.

As for the logging aspect, give some thought to using a queue of some sort - [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) by preference - to pass the actual logging operations off to another thread.  That way you spend a minimum of time in the actual hook function as well as reducing the chances of your hooks causing recursion.  You'll have to experiment with filtering in the logging thread vs the hook functions to find out which has the smaller performance impact on the system.

Always make sure you know how much data your program is dealing with and have a plan in place for dealing with the volume of data.  You're going to have to do some serious profiling to find the pain points, then put in plenty of work on reducing the overheads so that your program doesn't mess up the system too badly.

Personally I'd start with a small subset of the APIs you ultimately want to monitor, write code that works as well as you can make it, then move up to the full set of APIs.  Less chance that you'll kill your computer that way.